# "Python worker did not connect back in time" Error while running pyspark from pycharm

Tags: pyspark, pycharm

I am new to python and currently trying to write unit tests in python for spark.I have installed pycharm on windows and am using anaconda as interpreter.I am using python 3.5 with spark 2.1.0.
I am just writing a simple wordcount program for testing.But what am seeing is if i run below code it works completely fine

```
mylist= ["the" , "earth" , "revolves" , "arround" , "sun"]
rdd=sc.parallelize(mylist)
output=rdd.collect
print(output)
```

Issue comes when am applying any transformations.With basic transformations like map , flatMap am getting below error

```
    18/03/22 11:36:07 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker did not connect back in time
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:138)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:133)
        ... 12 more
18/03/22 11:36:07 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\PyUnittest\Testing\WordCount.py", line 30, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\PyUnittest\Testing\WordCount.py", line 26, in main
    output=rdd.map(lambda x: (x,1)).collect()
  File "C:\Users\<username>\spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py", line 809, in collect
  File "C:\Users\<username>\spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "C:\Users\<username>\spark\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker did not connect back in time
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:133)
    ... 12 more
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to shutdown your kernel, if you are using the Anaconda.

Since you are using yarn, I'd look at spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html specifically the "Debugging your Application" section.

Read:
[SparkException: Python worker did not connect back in time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225412/sparkexception-python-worker-did-not-connect-back-in-time)